# How to launch DHCP client in Linux?

Tags: wifi, dhcp

As a title, I found my wi-fi port without an IP address assigned, as follows.

```
ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:13:32:81:2c:d2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

That must be due to no configuration to launch the DHCP client. Or DHCP client failed to get correct response from DHCP server. How can I use the command to check if DHCP client can successfully request an IP configuration from the server? And how can I check if it's configured correctly for DHCP client to do request the start-up time?

ps. The distribution is 'Ubuntu 20.04'

Comment: Do you know **which** DHCP client(s) you're running (or are available) on the Linux distro (???? which one) you're using?

Comment: `wlan0` is a Wi-Fi adapter, so before DHCP client can begin, the adapter needs to be configured with a network name, and encryption parameters unless the network is completely open (unsafe). With the modern WPA encryption being the norm, this usually means having a `wpa-supplicant` or equivalent process needs to be running and configured with the name of the desired network. If you are running `NetworkManager` or some other system to manage your network configuration, it will usually handle the `wpa-supplicant` and the DHCP client for you.

Comment: I ran 'NetworkManager' and nothing happened or changed.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to say which distribution you are using: Ubuntu, centos, Debian, arch, ...? This might give us a hint. Different distributions do this in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

### Direct Configuration File Method

1. **Release current IP** (Optional)

   ```bash
   sudo dhclient -r wlan0
   ```
2. **Request new IP** (watch the output for a lease status)

   ```bash
   sudo dhclient -v wlan0
   ```
3. **Check the Network Interface Configuration File**: Check the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

   A DHCP-configured entry typically looks like this:

   ```
   auto wlan0
   iface wlan0 inet dhcp
   ```
4. **Check Configuration Using Command**: Use `grep -i dhcp /etc/network/interfaces` to search for DHCP-related configuration for the interface.
5. **Check for Network Manager**

   Look for network settings in the system settings panel.

### NetworkManager command-line tool

1. **Check the Current Configuration for `wlan0`**:

Use this command to check if `wlan0` is set to use DHCP for IPv4:

```bash
nmcli device show wlan0
```

Check the `IP4.CONFIGURATION` section for IPv4 configuration. If DHCP is used, it should be mentioned under the method.

2. **Modify `wlan0` to Use DHCP**:

List all NetworkManager connections to find the connection name to replace `<connection-name>`.

```bash
nmcli con show
```

If you're not using DHCP on `wlan0`, you can adjust its configuration by using this command:

```bash
nmcli con mod <connection-name> ipv4.method auto
```

3. **Apply Changes**:

Restart connection after DHCP changes.

```bash
nmcli con down <connection-name>
nmcli con up <connection-name>
```

Replace `<connection-name>` with your connection's name. This will restart the network connection using the new DHCP configuration.

Comment: @GAD3R Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I labeled "Direct Configuration File Method" sections in Tulikowski's answer as 1.x and "NetworkManager command-line tool" as 2.x, and below is the result I got by following the directions:

1.1 sudo dhclient -r wlan0 ==> nothing happened

1.2 sudo dhclient -v wlan0 ==> 

Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/


Listening on LPF/wlan0/b8:13:32:81:2c:d2
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/b8:13:32:81:2c:d2
Sending on   Socket/fallback

(to be continued)

Comment: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xdb5cba75)
.... endless showing the last line
1.3 No 'auto ... ' & 'iface' found at /etc/networks/interfaces
1.4 No 'dhcp' found at /etc/network/interfaces

2.1 nmcli device show wlan0 ==>>
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         B8:13:32:81:2C:D2
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                --

Comment: 2.2 nmcli con show ==>> 

NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
Wired connection 1  0a329729-ac77-38e6-a00f-8534f8ebf7ec  ethernet  --


nmcli con mod <connection-name> ipv4.method auto ==>> This direction can't be followed because of no wlan0 items found in the last command's output.


All commands from 2.3 can't be followed.